# Is there a nice explicit description of Verma modules when $\mathfrak{g} = \mathfrak{sl}_3(\mathbb{C})$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, representation-theory, lie-algebras

For reference, I've read through and generally understand the general construction at a high level. I've also read and understood Verma modules for $\mathfrak{sl}_2(\mathbb{C})$, but I can't link my understanding of what the Verma modules look like to the abstract definition of a Verma module. While I think an understanding of this would be nice, I was mainly wondering if there was any reference on an explicit description of what Verma modules look like for $\mathfrak{sl}_3(\mathbb{C})$. I assume it's very similar to the finite irreducible case, except there are infinitely many weights in both directions from the highest weight, but I want to make sure this is accurate and get a better description. For this, I'm just going off my intuition about what Verma modules and the $\mathfrak{sl}_2(\mathbb{C})$ case.

Comment: Yes, see [these notes](https://www.google.at/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=&ved=2ahUKEwjU796Y15TzAhUng_0HHY8FAeoQFnoECA8QAQ&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.math.columbia.edu%2F~woit%2FLieGroups-2012%2Fvermamodules.pdf&usg=AOvVaw0dS7dDhNjqYTPxWaLqhLZW). First the $\mathfrak{sl}(2)$ case is explained in detail, and then the general case, which you can do for $\mathfrak{sl}(3)$ almost in parallel.

Comment: In [this paper](https://www.google.at/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=&ved=2ahUKEwj66LnV2JTzAhVR_aQKHa1-Dew4ChAWegQIAhAB&url=https%3A%2F%2Facademic.oup.com%2Fptps%2Farticle-pdf%2Fdoi%2F10.1143%2FPTP.102.137%2F5373357%2F102-137.pdf&usg=AOvVaw15lLBCB_Chrl2PlldhHMkG) the case $\mathfrak{sl}(3)$ is done in the context of quantum groups, but also with results on Verma modules for it.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I've managed to explicitly go through it as I've wanted thanks to this.